# Send nested array of Files from Vuejs to Laravel

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to send a nested array of images to my laravel backend. But when I var_dump() the received array. The files are shown as empty php object.
Please guide what is the right way of send nested array of images to Laravel backend.

[image]

Comment: can you provide some code, *sending a nested array of images* can be done wrong in so many ways

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have added the picture. is it understandable now?

Comment: Array[3] is not much to go on, though POST'ing up plain old objects are sent over the network as a JSON string, so it won't work if each of the items is a new Image / FileReader / blob stream etc it would need to be sent inside a FormData object which then it will be sent as a multipart message, then picked up in php inside $_FILES or equivalent, alternatively, base64 encode each of the images and send strings and decode serverside, though its better to have a side channel which handles image or other media uploads else it would cause slow saves and timeouts